# How to change the load order of libraries in qt

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, g++, static-libraries

Im working on a opengl scenegraph for students. The scenegraph was created by someone else and we just want to hide it in libraries, to let the student focus on specific aspects.
I have created two static libraries with qt and now i want to load them.

The problem is the load order of these libraries in the makefile is different from the order in my .pro file.

-lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind are loaded before my own libraries int the makefile but in the .pro they are the first libs that i specified.

Is there a way to specify the load order that my libraries are loaded first?
I dont want to change it every time in the makefile.

Would appreaciate some help.

Here is the code form my .pro file

```
TARGET = 01_SimpleScene
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD
LIBS +=  -L$$PWD/ -lDSGqt \
         -L$$PWD/Bulletphysics/ -lBulletPhysics

QT += core gui
QT += opengl #needed for synchronizer3D and DSG
QT+= network #needed for synchronizer
QT += xml #needed for synchronizer


CONFIG += rtti thread #needed for synchronizer

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           scene.cpp

HEADERS  += scene.h
```

This is from my makefile:
LIBS        =        -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmain -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/ -lDSGqt -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/Bulletphysics/ -lBulletPhysics -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win32/ -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/ -lOpenAL32 -lalut -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/EFX-Util_MT/ -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/EFX-Util_MTDLL/ -lEFX-Util -LC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Xml -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core

and this is how i want it:
LIBS        =      -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/ -lDSGqt -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/Bulletphysics/ -lBulletPhysics  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind  -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win32/ -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/ -lOpenAL32 -lalut -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/EFX-Util_MT/ -LC:/Umgewandelt/Szenegraph/DSGqt/libs/OpenAL/Win64/EFX-Util_MTDLL/ -lEFX-Util -LC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5OpenGLd -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Xmld -lQt5Networkd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored

Comment: Odd, can you show your project file, namely the LIBS variable?

Comment: You could also show the link command you have now, and the link command you need.

Comment: I added the code from my .pro file and the order of the libs in the makefile.

Comment: My libs are normaly included in a .pri file. The openAl stuff is included after my own libraries and before the qt ones.